# HTTP SEARCH Method - Browser Support?

Tags: javascript, http, curl

I tried using cUrl to initiate a SEARCH request but it failed. Based on what I can find, cUrl does not seem to support SEARCH.

Looking around for JavaScript support for the SEARCH method in both XMLHttpRequest and Fetch but can't find anything explicitly saying SEARCH is supported.

Does anyone know how to send a SEARCH request via the browser?

Comment: I believe `SEARCH` method is not one of the [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) yet.

Comment: Form the [curl man page](https://manpages.org/curl): _"-X, --request <command>
(HTTP) Specifies a custom request method to use when communicating with the HTTP server. The specified request method will be used instead of the method otherwise used (which defaults to GET)."_ SEARCH, indeed any method, is supported by curl.

Comment: [the spec for fetch request](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-request-method) doesn't explicitly state any method other than GET either, you should be able to use whatever method you want.

Comment: Could you include your code that is failing and include any errors you are seeing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIU, every serious HTTP client (in particular curl, but browsers as well), "support" SEARCH (in that they can send that request).

It seems you're simply talking to a *server* that doesn't support SEARCH.